# In English the suffix sometimes changes the stress pattern of the rest of the word. Is English the only language with this system?

Tags: english, french, inflection, american-english, stress

TELephone, telePHONic, teLEphony. PHOTograph, photoGRAphic,photOgraphy. biOLogy, bioLOGical.

The suffix changes the stress pattern of the rest of the word. Is English the only language with this system or are there other languages, with the same or a closely analogous system? French seems to not have this.

Not sure whether Indian English and Singlish and other versions/descendants of English that don't have the normal stress patterns are foreign languages, creoles, pidgins, or dialects of English. Out of my depth with respect to that topic.

Comment: This is the case in a great many languages. I’d say probably most languages that (a) use derivational suffixes and (b) do not have fixed stress on a root syllable. At least I can’t think of any such languages where the addition of various suffixes _doesn’t_ change the stress. Most European languages do, at least (the exceptions being languages with fixed initial stress, such as Czech, Slovak, Icelandic, Faroese, most dialects of Irish and Scottish, Finnish, Estonian and Hungarian, and perhaps a few more).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - Albanian has fixed stress on root syllable (not fixed initial stress, but affected by the nature of the last syllable of the root), and when inflected, stress falls on the same syllable as in corresponding forms without overt inflection, even when the phonology would trigger a different stress position. See [Stress Uniformity in Albanian: Morphological Arguments for Cyclicity](https://direct.mit.edu/ling/article/44/1/109/538/Stress-Uniformity-in-Albanian-Morphological).

Comment: Stress is generally less marked in French than in other languages but nevertheless different between *télé**pho**ne* and *télépho**niqu**e*, *photo**gra**phe* and *photogra**phie***.

Comment: @jlliagre I never noticed that. Do you have some evidence?

Comment: @MatthewChristopherBartsh French is regularly stressed (albeit weakly) on the final syllable. Prior to the loss of final schwas, which is relatively recent, the rule was more complicated though

Comment: French has a prosodic stress. When isolated, the words cited as examples have the stress marked in bold. In whole sentences, only a few words keep their stress. See http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=4511 - https://halshs.archives-ouvertes.fr/halshs-00365006/PDF/vaissiere_1996_from_latin_to_modern_French.pdf - https://learnfrenchwithmanon.com/2018/09/05/le-rythme-du-francais/ Note also that French spoken in Southern France has stronger stresses than the other variants.

Comment: @Tristan When did the final schwas get lost, and do you mean those four words all had the final e pronounced as a schwa? That was the case with final e's in in English in Shakespeare's time, I think. With all e's?

Comment: The final schwa is not necessarily lost. It can still be pronounced in careful speech, in poetry or songs (e.g. *Frères Jacques*) and is also regularly realized by millions of native French speakers (the same as those who stress their words a lot).

Comment: @jlliagre What does 'stress their words a lot' mean? Do you mean they stress each and every word heavily? Do you have a link to an audio recording of someone speaking like this? Also, how about for this interesting claim (I'm not being sarcastic): 
"Stress is generally less marked in French than in other languages but nevertheless different between téléphone and téléphonique, photographe and photographie."

Comment: 1. I mean people who stress individual words unlike Parisian French where stress is more sentence based. [Here is a talk about Marseille accent](https://vimeo.com/86877607)  2. Whatever the French variant, when these word are pronounced isolated from other ones, the stress is located at different syllables.

Comment: If you are more comfortable with English, you might also have a look to [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bO5eq6dOPok).

Comment: @jlliagre I am more comfortable with English, by a long chalk. I'm not that good at French. I watched the video you linked to. It didn't clarify much for me. The young woman doing the explaining seemed to transition into talking about endangered languages in France, and indeed seemed to conflate accents and languages, which I found confusing. The host seemed to notice, and indicated as much with a forced smile, or so I thought.

Comment: There is actually a strong relationship between the various languages that used to be widely spoken and are sometimes still although more marginally spoken in some regions of France and the accent of the people originating or living in these regions when they speak French. Back to your question about the final E's, they can all be pronounced by southerners accented people. Here is another [link](https://www.frenchlanguagecoach.com/en/3-tips-to-recognize-southern-french-accent/).

Comment: Have a look to https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zXT7diONJ4Q&t=48s [Pierre Escude](https://laces.u-bordeaux.fr/membres/escude-pierre/) talks about Toulouse accent and says: "It has a stress on words,, not just on sentences so it will say: [la.pə.ˈti.tə.ˈf.ijə.va.a.le.ˈkɔ.lə] (11 syllables, multiple stresses) and not [la.ptit.fij.va.a.lɛ.ˈkɔl] (7 syllables, one single weak stress)"

Comment: The sentence being: *La petite fille va à l'école*.

Comment: @jlliagre https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fyWUwH6WzeM I liked this video which says much the same thing about the accents of British English. My French is not good enough to get much out of the videos in French. Regarding the article you linked to, "In France, there are many accents that, in fact, come from the old languages or dialects of France. Before the Second World War, there were still areas where people spoke French only at school." says the author, but she doesn't say what those people spoke when not at school. Do you happen to know?

Comment: @jlliagre I read the article carefully and listened to the recordings several times each, but all I could hear was the pronunciation of some of the silent e's and and the change to -ng from nasalization, and the vowel changes. I could not hear any change in stress, I'm sorry to say.

Comment: Languages that were spoken when not at school were diverse. The three main families were *Langue d'oïl* dialects in the half North of France, like Picard, Norman, Gallo, Champenois, Franc-Comtois, *Langue d'Oc* (Occitan) dialects like Provençal, Gascon, Auvergnat, *Franco-Provençal* dialects (Arpitan). In addition, Catalan, Basque, Corsican, Alsatian, Breton, Flemish, Francique. This map gives a good picture of this diversity: https://atlas.limsi.fr/?tab=Hexagone

Comment: I was expecting your remark about the stress. The issue is the person speaking is unable to refrain from stressing his words even if he is more successful with other characteristics.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124457/discussion-between-jlliagre-and-matthew-christopher-bartsh).

Answer (score 1):

I think Ancient Greek and Russian are also examples of languages, where the addition of suffixes changes the way the original stem was stressed.

Answer (score 0):

In fact this kind of stress system goes back to Latin, where stress falls to the penultimate or ante-penultimate syllable depending on the length of the last syllables. A syllable counts as long when either its vowel is long or when it is a closed syllable ending in a consonant.

Comment: To Latin, as well as to Greek and other Indo-European languages (with different rules, of course). And heavily adjusted within English itself, as well; _-y_ derivations have antepaenultimate stress, whereas the ancestor of the suffix was stressed on the vowel that eventually became _-y_.

Comment: You are not (I think) really claiming that in English the stress depends on vowel length. It is just that it sounds as though you are. ("This kind of stress system goes back to Latin").

Comment: No, but for borrowed words from Latin there is also a borrowing of the stress (with the original stress patterns being obscured over time)